# Core Data model attribute types not compatible with program types

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm following an example from an iOS programming book. The example in the book downloads photos from Flickr and place them in a collection view. Each photo are downloaded through a link as one of the elements of an object in a json code. The example uses Core Data for persistence of data and involves conversion from Core Data managed object type to custom object type.

The compiler reports that "Cannot convert value of type '[Photo]' to expected argument type '[FlickrPhoto]'". The [Photo] is an array of Photo objects which are automatically generated by Core Data according to Entity and Attributes information provided by me and the [FlickrPhoto] is an array of FlickrPhoto objects which are custom objects.

Please let me know what problem there is and suggest some solutions. Thank you!

Relevant code is as follows:

Photo+CoreDataClass.swift

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

@objc(Photo)
public class Photo: NSManagedObject {

}
```

Photo+CoreDataProperties.swift

```
import Foundation
import CoreData


extension Photo {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Photo> {
        return NSFetchRequest<Photo>(entityName: "Photo")
    }

    @NSManaged public var datetaken: String?
    @NSManaged public var datetakengranularity: String?
    @NSManaged public var datetakenunknow: String?
    @NSManaged public var farm: Int64
    @NSManaged public var heightZ: Int64
    @NSManaged public var id: String?
    @NSManaged public var isfamily: Int64
    @NSManaged public var isfriend: Int64
    @NSManaged public var ispublic: Int64
    @NSManaged public var owner: String?
    @NSManaged public var secret: String?
    @NSManaged public var server: String?
    @NSManaged public var title: String?
    @NSManaged public var urlZ: String?
    @NSManaged public var widthZ: Int64

}

extension Photo : Identifiable {

}
```

Photo.swift

```
import Foundation

struct FlickrPhoto: Codable {
    let id, owner, secret, server: String
    let farm: Int
    let title: String
    let ispublic, isfriend, isfamily: Int
    let datetaken: String
    let datetakengranularity: Datetakengranularity
    let datetakenunknown: String
    let urlZ: String?
    let heightZ, widthZ: Int?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id, owner, secret, server, farm, title, ispublic, isfriend, isfamily, datetaken, datetakengranularity, datetakenunknown
        case urlZ = "url_z"
        case heightZ = "height_z"
        case widthZ = "width_z"
    }
}
enum Datetakengranularity: Codable {
    case integer(Int)
    case string(String)

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        if let x = try? container.decode(Int.self) {
            self = .integer(x)
            return
        }
        if let x = try? container.decode(String.self) {
            self = .string(x)
            return
        }
        throw DecodingError.typeMismatch(Datetakengranularity.self, DecodingError.Context(codingPath: decoder.codingPath, debugDescription: "Wrong type for Datetakengranularity"))
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
        switch self {
        case .integer(let x):
            try container.encode(x)
        case .string(let x):
            try container.encode(x)
        }
    }
}

extension FlickrPhoto: Equatable {
    static func == (lhs: FlickrPhoto, rhs: FlickrPhoto) -> Bool {
        // Two Photos are the same if they have the same photoID
        return lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
}
```

PhotoStore.swift

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class PhotoStore {
    private let session: URLSession = {
        let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        return URLSession(configuration: config)
    }()
    let imageStore = ImageStore()
    let persistenContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
        let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "Photorama")
        container.loadPersistentStores { (description, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error setting up Core Data (\(error))")
            }
        }
        return container
    }()
    private func processPhotosRequest (data: Data?, error: Error?) ->
    Result<[FlickrPhoto], Error> {
        guard let jsonData = data else {
            return .failure(error!)
        }
        //return FlickrAPI.photos(fromJSON: jsonData)
        let context = persistenContainer.viewContext
        
        switch FlickrAPI.photos(fromJSON: jsonData) {
        case let .success(flickrPhotos):
            let photos = flickrPhotos.map { flickrPhoto -> Photo in
                var photo: Photo!
                context.performAndWait {
                    do {
                        photo = Photo(context: context)
                        photo.id = flickrPhoto.id
                        photo.owner = flickrPhoto.owner
                        photo.secret = flickrPhoto.secret
                        photo.server = flickrPhoto.server
                        photo.farm = Int64(flickrPhoto.farm)
                        photo.title = flickrPhoto.title
                        photo.ispublic = Int64(flickrPhoto.ispublic)
                        photo.isfriend = Int64(flickrPhoto.isfriend)
                        photo.isfamily = Int64(flickrPhoto.isfamily)
                        photo.datetaken = flickrPhoto.datetaken
                        photo.datetakengranularity = try String(from: flickrPhoto.datetakengranularity as! Decoder)
                        photo.datetakenunknow = flickrPhoto.datetakenunknown
                        photo.urlZ = flickrPhoto.urlZ
                        photo.heightZ = Int64(flickrPhoto.heightZ!)
                        photo.widthZ = Int64(flickrPhoto.widthZ!)
                    } catch {
                        print("error encountered")
                    }
                }
                return photo
            }
            return .success(photos) // Compiler reports the above mentioned error here
        case let .failure(error):
            return .failure(error)
        }
    }
    
    func fetchInterestingPhotos (completion: @escaping (Result<[FlickrPhoto], Error>) -> Void) {
        let url = FlickrAPI.interestingPhotoURL
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        let task = session.dataTask(with: request) {
            (data, response, error) in
            
            let result = self.processPhotosRequest(data: data, error: error)
            OperationQueue.main.addOperation {
                completion(result)
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
    func fetchImage (for photo: FlickrPhoto, completion: @escaping (Result<UIImage, Error>) -> Void) {
        
        let photoKey = photo.id
        if let image = imageStore.image(forKey: photoKey) {
            OperationQueue.main.addOperation {
                completion(.success(image))
            }
            return
        }
        guard let photoURL = photo.urlZ else { return }
        guard let requestURL = URL(string: photoURL)  else {
            completion(.failure(PhotoError.missingImageURL))
            return
        }
        let request = URLRequest(url: requestURL)
        let task = session.dataTask(with: request) {
            (data, response, error) in
            let result = self.processImageRequest(data: data, error: error)
            if case let .success(image) = result {
                self.imageStore.setImage(image, forKey: photoKey)
            }
            OperationQueue.main.addOperation {
                completion(result)
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
    private func processImageRequest (data: Data?, error: Error?) -> Result<UIImage, Error> {
        guard let imageData = data,
              let image = UIImage(data: imageData) else {
            // Couldn't create an image
            if data == nil {
                return .failure(error!)
            } else {
                return .failure(PhotoError.imageCreationError)
            }
        }
        return .success(image)
    }
}

enum PhotoError: Error {
    case imageCreationError
    case missingImageURL
}
```

Lastly, a snapshot of the xcdatamodeld setup:

[image]

More code will be provided as needed.

Comment: Thanks, @JoakimDanielson, for your response. My question is as the title suggested, photos is of the Photo type which is automatically generated by the Core Data model which the program configures by adding an entity and its attributes according to the properties of FlickrPhoto struct. However, when the code in the 'return .success(photos)' statement in 'processPhotosRequest' method intends to use photos which is of the '[Photo]' type as the argument to '.success()' whose argument, however, should be of the '[FlickrPhoto]' type, the compiler reports gives the complaint as shown in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the function `processPhotosRequest` there is a mapping from FlickrPhoto to Photo objects which is done so the data can be stored in Core Data but it is *not* those objects that should be returned so the row

```
return .success(photos)
```

should be changed to

```
return .success(flickrPhotos)
```

to fix the compilation error and return the right thing.

Furthermore some changes can be done to the mapping of objects since you do not need to keep an array of Photo objects

```
case let .success(flickrPhotos):
    flickrPhotos.forEach { flickrPhoto -> Photo in
        context.performAndWait {
            do {
                let photo = Photo(context: context)
                //rest of mapping is the same
                
                context.save()
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
```

Here I also added a `save()` call so that your data is saved to the Core Data store since I couldn't find such a call elsewhere in your code

Comment: Thank you very much, @Joakim Danielson. The solution provided by you solved the problem I was asking. But another problem persisted. The context.save() method call is in another source file of the program, which I didn't show here.

Comment: Then you can remove my save if you want and also the whole do/catch